# Windows 10 - Signing in with Local Account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, microsoft-account

I'm trying to sign in with a local account instead of the Microsoft account currently linked with the user (had to link it for a program, no longer use that program), but every time I do, I get an error:
[image: image of error Code 0x80004005]

After googling this error and trying just about everything I could find, I've come to the conclusion that, though everything in the registry appears to be assigned as a local user, that something somewhere is still displaying it as a linked Microsoft account. Anyone know where I can go to manually fix this?

Thanks.

Edit: More info, new accounts do not have this issue, but I don't want to make a new account and lose all of the saved settings and installed apps per user :(

Comment: well, it's currently broken, so i'd rather just it commit to one fully :P

Comment: @Appleoddity - Can we please not spread conspiracy theories like how Microsoft is going to spy on you?

Comment: @Run5k It's removed

Comment: @vidsac From Meta:[Is bumping a question OK?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5485/is-bumping-a-question-ok)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your Microsoft account is not synced properly. Please try following steps to check related service, and enable Sync before trying to switch account again:

1. Press Win + R from your keyboard, input **services.msc** and click OK button.
2. Within the **Services** window, locate the **Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant** from the list, double click on it, and change the **Startup Type** to **Delayed Start**.
3. You also need to check those services including **Remote Procedure Call, Local Session Manager, and User Accounts Service**. Make sure all of them are set to Automatic.
4. Then open **Setting** app, go to **Account** > **Sync** your settings, and enable the Sync setting feature.

If this issue still persist, let's Remove your PC from the list of devices online, and try again:
Re-connecting your PC with your account can often solve this issue, and you will be able to switch to a local account afterwards.

1. Open the Start menu by pressing the Windows key on your keyboard and
   click the gear icon to open the Settings Go to Accounts, and then
   Sign-in Options.
2. Click on Change Pin. Create a new pin, and change
   the password as well.
3. Open your browser of choice, and go to
   hotmail.com. Sign-in with your Microsoft account and the new
   password you just changed.
4. When you log in, click on your name, and
   open Account settings. On the next screen you’re presented with,
   scroll down until you find Click on See all.
5. Find your device and
   click Remove PC. Wait for it to sync with your PC, make sure you
   have a decent internet connection.

Once this is done, go to your settings and switch to a local account again.

Please also try the Microsoft account troubleshooter tool to see if the issue can be fixed: https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/4/F24D0C03-4181-4E5B-A23B-5C3A6B5974E3/microsoftaccounts.diagcab

Comment: I don't have Windows Live ID `Sign-In Assistant`, `Live Update`, or `User Accounts Service` as services. `Remote Procedure Call` and `Local Session Manager` are already automatic (and running). I'm not able to sync my settings, there's a yellow message at the top: `Some Windows features are only available if you are using a Microsoft account or work account.` Clicking the "Add" button under PIN does nothing, I can click it an infinite number of times. I can't even change my password!

Comment: Seem you didn't use Microsoft account on your PC according to the message. Please check Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant service, I have edited my reply.

Comment: [See this image](https://i.imgur.com/QqOTPBN.png)

Comment: Please try this (https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4026971/microsoft-account-how-to-reset-your-microsoft-account-password) to reset your Microsoft account password, then Login back on the PC, try again. By the way, have you check the status of Microsoft account sigh-in Assistant service? Also try the Microsoft account troubleshooter in my original reply.

Comment: The Microsoft account was deleted a while ago when I tried to get support from Microsoft directly...

Comment: So your issue has been resolved??? Would you please share what you have done?

Comment: No, it isn't resolved. I'm still waiting for other people to reply and post their answers :)